# AngularJS controller data from AJAX - does not always work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am using Angular 1.4.7 with `angular-ui-router 0.2.15` as state router. My standard controller looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('App.Page1',[....]);
app.controller('Page1Ctrl',['$scope' ... ,function($scope ...) {
...
  $scope.records = [];

  // jsRoutes.controllers.Page1.list() - is ajax wrapper
  jsRoutes.controllers.Page1.listitems().ajax({
    success: function(data) { 
       console.log("RECV",data);
       $scope.records = data 
    },
    error: function(res){ console.log("ERROR",res); }
  });
});
```

And controller template that just rolls out records:

```
<h1>Page1</h1>
<div ng-repeat="record in records" class="row">
    {{record.name}} ...
</div>
```

It works but not stable. Sometimes I am receiving a page only with the header. Looks like parsers array is empty but I see in Network requests that list request was successfully received and success function was called. After refreshing a page, I see my data again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax service call is outside the context of AngularJS. 
Hence you need to explicitly inform Angular that some data has changed.

This can be done calling `$scope.$apply()` in your success function after you assign data to your $scope variable.

`$scope.parsers  =  data;
$scope.$apply();`

This should solve your issue.